# Emacs lisp advice to start ipython repl in the project root

Tags: lisp, elisp

When starting an ipython repl for my project at work, I pretty much always want it started in the project root, not adjacent to the file for the buffer I'm viewing (this is python and module loading depends on cwd). While I can always start the repl and then `%cd /my/project/root` that is a pain the 50th time I had to do it. So I figured I could do some digging and get emacs to do it for me.

I guessed correctly that setting `default-directory` would do the trick and wheee with dynamic scoping I can just run the code in a `let` and set it to `(projectile-project-root)`. This becomes a straightforward matter therefore of writing `:around` advice which I've never done before but I think I got it.

The remaining issue is that I don't *always* want this to happen. Instead I want it to only happen within my big work project monorepo so I need some way of controlling whether the advice was active via a variable I can set with `dir-locals`. The following is what I came up with

```
    (defcustom gim/default-directory-to-projectile-root-is-active nil
      "Control whether the gim/default-directory-to-projectile-root advice is currently active or not"
      :type '(boolean))

    (defun gim/default-directory-to-projectile-root (orig-fun &rest args)
      (if (not gim/default-directory-to-projectile-root-is-active)
          (apply orig-fun args)
          (let ((default-directory (projectile-project-root)))
              (apply orig-fun args))))

    (advice-remove 'spacemacs/python-start-or-switch-repl #'gim/default-directory-to-projectile-root)
    (advice-add 'spacemacs/python-start-or-switch-repl :around #'gim/default-directory-to-projectile-root)
```

Thoughts? Suggestions? Is around advice right? Is this a good way of doing a flag? The duplication on both branches of the `if` statement is annoying, surely there is a slicker way to do that